# Executing a Thread on a different platform (64bit)

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

A bit of a long shot.

I have a 32 bits app. There is some code within it that would perform better under 64 bit. I cannot convert my entire app to 64 bit.

So, can I run part of my app under a different process but also on a 64 bit process?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't. The bits the application is running on is specified on the process, not on a thread or AppDomain.

The only alternative you have it to create a separate executable that runs on other bits. Call that process from your main process. If necessary, you can use some messaging mechanism to exchange information between the two like one of the classes that derives [PipeStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I am looking at IPC now. Thanks

Comment: See the last part of my answer on that.